# 3D brain tumor datasets for classification

Tags: images

I am a research master student and I need the data to finish my thesis, I would like a MRI brain tumor dataset for classification, which contains certain classes from this list (malignant, benign, atypica, pituitary adenoma, pituitary cacinoma, craniopharvngioma, rathke's cleft cyst) Would you suggest a database please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Brain Tumor Classification (MRI)](https://www.kaggle.com/sartajbhuvaji/brain-tumor-classification-mri) with four Classes MRI images into four classes

- glioma_tumor
- meningioma_tumor
- no_tumor
- pituitary_tumor

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/SartajBhuvaji/Brain-Tumor-Classification-DataSet)

The folder contains MRI data. The images are already split into Training and Testing folders.
Each folder has more four subfolders. These folders have MRIs of respective tumor classes.

---

The [Multimodal Brain Tumor Image Segmentation Benchmark (BRATS)](http://braintumorsegmentation.org/) is a challenge focused on brain tumor segmentation and occurs on a yearly basis on MICCAI.
This dataset, from the 2015 challenge, contains data and expert annotations on four types of MRI images:

- T1
- T1c
- T2
- FLAIR

**[Download Here](https://www.kaggle.com/andrewmvd/brain-tumor-segmentation-in-mri-brats-2015)**

---

[Brain Tumor Segmentation(BraTS2020)](https://www.kaggle.com/awsaf49/brats2020-training-data)

---

**Additional References**

- [BITE: Brain Images of Tumors for Evaluation database](http://nist.mni.mcgill.ca/?page_id=672)
- [Brain Tumor Segmentation](https://paperswithcode.com/task/brain-tumor-segmentation)
- [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/search?q=Brain%20Tumor%20in%3Adatasets)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I found that BRATS 2020 (3D images) contains two classes among the classes I am looking for (HGG / LGG) so I will use it.
I just have to look for other datasets (3D images) that contain the other classes
thank you